# Drop event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

So i have implemented this logic for a drag and drop area, where if the user adds a non image file, i alert the user that the file is not an image and its a invalid format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eITxv.png)

But once i press ok, the alert reappears again, and continues multiple times sometimes (i counted this actually and the count is equal to the number of times u have drag and dropped a file). Here is the relevant code of the method:

```
function setDropZoneWithCropper() {
var toBeCroppedImage = document.getElementById('toBeCroppedImage');
droparea = document.querySelector("#add-to-be-cropped-image-section");

droparea.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    droparea.classList.add("draggableImageHover");
});

droparea.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    droparea.classList.remove("draggableImageHover");
});

droparea.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const image = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    const type = image.type;

    if (
        type == "image/png" ||
        type == "image/jpg" ||
        type == "image/jpeg"
    ) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // reader.onload = function (event) {
        //     passImageToCropper(reader.result);
        // };
        // reader.readAsDataURL(file)

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            if(reader.result !== null){
                passImageToCropper(reader.result);
            }
        };

        if (image) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Invalid File Format!");
    }
});
```

}

As you can see, the addEvent listener which is :

```
    droparea.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const image = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    const type = image.type;

    if (
        type == "image/png" ||
        type == "image/jpg" ||
        type == "image/jpeg"
    ) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // reader.onload = function (event) {
        //     passImageToCropper(reader.result);
        // };
        // reader.readAsDataURL(file)

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            if(reader.result !== null){
                passImageToCropper(reader.result);
            }
        };

        if (image) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } else {
        alert("Invalid File Format!");
    }
});
```

Addevent listener Drop fires multiple times which i got to know by some console logs, how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, add this inside the else clause after the alert :

```
 else {
            alert("Invalid File Format!");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
```